# Delete Firebase entry angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key

I've looked for quite a bit for an answer to this question. Followed documentation on AngularFire 2 and Angular 2 itself but I can't find a working answer. I simply want to delete an entry in my firebase database using the unique key. I could probably do this in Angular 4 but I'm having to do this for Angular 2.

Any support would be greatly appreciated!

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listings',
  templateUrl: './listings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listings.component.scss']
})
export class ListingsComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  item: FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('Harry');
    this.item = db.object('/Harry/');
  }
  delete() {
    this.item.remove(); // removes all data.
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

EDIT: Added the HTML

```html
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <p><strong>Name: </strong>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p><strong>Email: </strong>{{item.email}}</p>
    <p><strong>Mobile: </strong>{{item.mobile}}</p>
    <p><strong>Address: </strong>{{item.address}}</p>
    <div class="editDel row">
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button class="btn-primary">Edit</button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button class="btn-danger" (click)="delete()">Delete</button></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Added package versions

```js
{
  "name": "ng2-firebase-addresslist",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "angular2-flash-messages": "^1.0.8",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7-pre",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

So I've noticed a lot of the guides and tutorials differ wildly on this topic mostly because different versions of AngularFire2 change how this works each time. An issue which has caused a lot of frustration for someone like myself who is learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved it using a slightly different method.

I noticed posting this in my HTML gave me my individual key for each firebase object.

```
<p><strong>Item Key: </strong>{{item.$key}}</p>
```

So I then took it a step further and included it in my onClick function.

```
<button class="btn-danger" (click)="deleteObject(this.item.$key)">Delete</button>
```

Which I then fed into my function in listings.components.ts

```
deleteObject(itemKey) {
 this.db.object('/Harry/' + itemKey).remove();
}
```

That successfully ended up removing the objects by their key one-by-one! Thanks for everyones support here that helped me along the way. Also AngularFire2, get better documentation!!!

Comment: Ha! Actually, it's nothing to do with Firebase per se - just mixed up modelling in the app. So `this.item` seems to serve no purpose? Was assuming it was equivalent to `this.selectedItem`, hence my question about the '/Harry/' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

delete() {
  this.items.remove(this.item)
}
```

***Edit***

A couple of other things don't look quite right

```
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('Harry');
    this.item = db.object('/Harry/');
  }
```

should be

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = this.db.list('Harry');
    this.item = this.db.object('/Harry/');
  }
```

<s>You may want to also move the code in constructor to `ngOnInit`, as AngularFire might not be ready within the constructor.</s>  Not necessary, according to example linked below.

***Edit #2***

The template looks almost ok, but because `items` is now `FirebaseListObservable`, need to access the iterated item with $value

```
<p><strong>Name: </strong>{{item.$value.name}}</p>
<p><strong>Email: </strong>{{item.$value.email}}</p>
<p><strong>Mobile: </strong>{{item.$value.mobile}}</p>
<p><strong>Address: </strong>{{item.$value.address}}</p>
```

Or, use `this.items = db.list('Harry').valueChanges()`, as per this example in docs [Example of persisting a Document Id](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#example-of-persisting-a-document-id)

***Edit #3***

Since you have to use a specific release, I thought it might be useful to take a look at the source for the specific release (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/releases). 2.0.0-beta.7, although you may have 2.0.0-beta.8.

You may have heard the term 'documentation rots', which means better to look at code and specs when dealing with an older release.

The relevent spec is

```
describe('remove', () => {

    it('should call remove on the underlying ref', () => {
      var removeSpy = spyOn(ref, 'remove');

      O.subscribe();
      O.remove();
      expect(removeSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
    });

    it('should throw an exception if removed when not subscribed', () => {
      O = new FirebaseObjectObservable((observer:Observer<any>) => {});

      expect(() => {
        O.remove();
      }).toThrowError('No ref specified for this Observable!')
    });

    it('should resolve returned thenable when successful', (done:any) => {
      O.remove().then(done, done.fail);
    });

  });
```

where `O` is equivalent to your `this.item`. Try is adding `this.item.subscribe()` to your delete method.

Also, when you retrieve item, why '/Harry/' and not '/Harry'?

And, you could wrap the operation in a promise to capture errors. From 'docs\2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md',

> The promise can be useful to chain multiple operations, catching
>   possible errors from security rules denials, or for debugging.
>
> `const promise = af.database.object('/item').remove();
>   promise.then(_ => console.log('success'))
>     .catch(err => console.log(err, 'You dont have access!'));`

Comment: I get the error 'property does not exist on type Observable<any[]>' unfortunately

Comment: items should be `FirebaseListObservable`

Comment: So I switched it around and now I've got this error

```/Users/admin/Documents/web/angularfire-addressbook/src/app/components/listings/listings.component.ts (18,23): Argument of type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseOperation'.
  Type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'AFUnwrappedDataSnapshot'.
    Property '$key' is missing in type 'FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>'.'```

Comment: Did this error occur when you clicked delete, or on mount? Also, could you please show the template as well in case it's something in there.

Comment: Please put the html up in the question, makes it easier to see.

Comment: I've added the HTML and I've also added the package.json because the version I'm using does not support .valueChanges()

Any idea the technique needed to access an object key for this version?

I tried using this.item.$ref.key in a console log but that only returns 'Harry' and not the actual unique key of the object!

Comment: this.item.$ref.key ==== 'Harry' seems logical to me, since that's what you use to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let item of items | async'>
        <td>{{item.in}}</td>
        <td>{{item.des}}</td>
        <td>{{item.cast}}</td>
        <td>{{item.tomi}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ris}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button (click)="deleteItem(item)" class= "btn btn-danger"> delete </button> 
              
         </div>
        <td>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>

**

 - .ts file

**
deleteItem(user: User) {
    const confirmBox = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (confirmBox) {
      this.service.deleteUser(user.id).then(() => {
        this.snackBar.open('visitor has been deleted successfully...', 'close');
      });
    }
  }

**

 - service

**
  constructor(private fireStore: AngularFirestore) { }

deleteUser(id: string): any {
    return this.fireStore.doc(`${this.dbName}/` + id).delete();
  }
```