# Angular Firebase Crud, Delete List item From Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

im currently able to push Data into my realtime Database in Firebase.

I store my data into a list and that is working well. I added a delete button next to my list items which i list in html.

But im not able to delete that list item im clicking on.. Any help how i can delete that specific list item?

Here is some of the specific html:

```
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor='let item of items | async'>
        <td>{{item.in}}</td>
        <td>{{item.des}}</td>
        <td>{{item.cast}}</td>
        <td>{{item.tomi}}</td>
        <td>{{item.ris}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button (click)="deleteItem()" class= "btn btn-danger"> delete </button> 
              
         </div>
        <td>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

and my deleteItem method is declared as followed in my component .ts:

```
deleteItem(){
     this.db.list('items').remove();
   }
```

With this current function im deleting all items. but i want to delete just the one im clicking on...

I know i need to get this id of the list item in the database, but neither [image]

```
item.id or item.$key is working..
```

What am i doing wrong and how can i delete the specific list item?

Ty in advance and best regards

Comment: Pass id via `(click)="deleteItem(item.id)"` and then use this id when calling server to delete (see firebase docs).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete Firebase entry angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655609/delete-firebase-entry-angular-2)

Comment: I tried that but it is not working :(